# Using jQuery to select direct child of div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select a direct child of an element. For example, given a DOM structured as:

```
<div class="track">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="track">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="track">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on say the first track div, how can I grab the immediate a and b underneath it?

I've tried using

```
$(this).children(".a");

$(this).find(".a");
```

but it always grabs references to the very bottom track instead. Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: My problem lied in another section of my code where I was temporarily referencing a track. Therefore, when I would click on a track, it would reference a different track. Thank you all for your help though!

Comment: Can you post your `.click()` code and other relevant code? This code should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fAEcR/) Reference

```
$(".track").click(function(){
    alert($(this).children(".a").html());
    alert($(this).children(".b").html());
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `children()` is correct, so the problem must be in your broader implementation, involving the `.click()` handler. Can you post more of your code?

This kind of thing would work:

```
$('.track').click(function(){
   var trackChildren = $(this).children(); //will get you .a and .b for whichever .track was clicked
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pE8Ae/).